# Drawn Circles Not Aligning

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to draw a clock face uiview and have referenced [this example](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/11/swift-how-to-draw-clock-face-using.html).

I've been able to successfully get the base circle drawn including the ticker marks, however, it appears the overlapping circles are unaligned on the x-axis where the ticker circle pokes out to the right of the base circle. My confusion is that the circles share the same x/y center coordinate and am admittedly lost..

Below is the code for reference...

```
class ClockView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect:CGRect)

{
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let rad = rect.width / 4

    let endAngle = CGFloat.pi * 2

    ctx?.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midY, y: rect.midY), radius: rad, startAngle: 0, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

    ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.gray.cgColor)

    ctx?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)

    ctx?.setLineWidth(4.0)

    ctx?.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)

    secondMarkers(ctx!, rect.midX, rect.midY, rad, 48, UIColor.white)
}

func degree2Radian(a:CGFloat)-> CGFloat {
    let b = CGFloat.pi * a/180
    return b
}

func secondMarkers(_ ctx: CGContext,_ x: CGFloat,_ y: CGFloat,_ radius: CGFloat,_ tickCount: Int,_ color: UIColor) {
    let points = circleCircumferencePoints(tickCount,x,y,radius)

    var divider: CGFloat = 1/8
    var counter = 0
    for p in points {
        if counter % 4 == 0 {
            divider = 1/4
        }
        else {
            divider = 1/8
        }

        let xn = p.x + divider*(x-p.x)
        let yn = p.y + divider*(y-p.y)

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: p.x, y: p.y))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xn, y: yn))
        path.closeSubpath()

        ctx.addPath(path)
        counter += 1
    }

    let cgcolor = color.cgColor
    ctx.setStrokeColor(cgcolor)
    ctx.setLineWidth(3.0)
    ctx.strokePath()
}

func circleCircumferencePoints(_ tickCount:Int,_ x:CGFloat,_ y:CGFloat,_ radius:CGFloat,_ adjustment:CGFloat=0)->[CGPoint] {
    let angle = degree2Radian(a: 360/CGFloat(tickCount))
    let cx = x
    let cy = y
    let r  = radius
    var i = tickCount
    var points = [CGPoint]()
    while points.count <= sides {
        let xpo = cx - r * cos(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2Radian(a: adjustment))
        let ypo = cy - r * sin(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2Radian(a: adjustment))
        points.append(CGPoint(x: xpo, y: ypo))
        i -= 1;
    }
    return points
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your result?

Comment: BTW, there are `60` minutes in an hour, not `48`, and you'll want a longer marker when `counter % 5 == 0`.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `sides` in the `circleCircumferencePoints` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code in a Playground with this view:

```
let clock = ClockView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 400))
```

The result was:

[image: clock in Playground]

Your problem is this line:

```
ctx?.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midY, y: rect.midY), radius: rad, startAngle: 0, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
```

You are using `rect.midY` as the horizontal center of your view and I assume your view isn't square.  Change that to `rect.midX`:

```
ctx?.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rad, startAngle: 0, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
```

**Other problems:**

1. `sides` is not defined.  I just set it to `60` to get this to compile.
2. You are using a value of `48` for your seconds, and there are `60` in an hour.

   Change:

   ```
   secondMarkers(ctx!, rect.midX, rect.midY, rad, 48, UIColor.white)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   secondMarkers(ctx!, rect.midX, rect.midY, rad, 60, UIColor.white)
   ```
3. You need a longer divider every `5` ticks, not `4`.

   Change:

   ```
   if counter % 4 == 0 {
   ```

   to:

   ```
   if counter % 5 == 0 {
   ```

---

With the suggested changes, the result is now:

[image: clock after]

---

Here is the complete code:

```
class ClockView: UIView {

    let sides = 60

    override func draw(_ rect:CGRect)

    {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        let rad = rect.width / 4

        let endAngle = CGFloat.pi * 2

        ctx?.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY), radius: rad, startAngle: 0, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

        ctx?.setFillColor(UIColor.gray.cgColor)

        ctx?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)

        ctx?.setLineWidth(4.0)

        ctx?.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)

        secondMarkers(ctx!, rect.midX, rect.midY, rad, 60, UIColor.white)
    }

    func degree2Radian(a:CGFloat)-> CGFloat {
        let b = CGFloat.pi * a/180
        return b
    }

    func secondMarkers(_ ctx: CGContext,_ x: CGFloat,_ y: CGFloat,_ radius: CGFloat,_ tickCount: Int,_ color: UIColor) {
        let points = circleCircumferencePoints(tickCount,x,y,radius)

        var divider: CGFloat = 1/8
        var counter = 0
        for p in points {
            if counter % 5 == 0 {
                divider = 1/4
            }
            else {
                divider = 1/8
            }

            let xn = p.x + divider*(x-p.x)
            let yn = p.y + divider*(y-p.y)

            let path = CGMutablePath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: p.x, y: p.y))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xn, y: yn))
            path.closeSubpath()

            ctx.addPath(path)
            counter += 1
        }

        let cgcolor = color.cgColor
        ctx.setStrokeColor(cgcolor)
        ctx.setLineWidth(3.0)
        ctx.strokePath()
    }

    func circleCircumferencePoints(_ tickCount:Int,_ x:CGFloat,_ y:CGFloat,_ radius:CGFloat,_ adjustment:CGFloat=0)->[CGPoint] {
        let angle = degree2Radian(a: 360/CGFloat(tickCount))
        let cx = x
        let cy = y
        let r  = radius
        var i = tickCount
        var points = [CGPoint]()
        while points.count <= sides {
            let xpo = cx - r * cos(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2Radian(a: adjustment))
            let ypo = cy - r * sin(angle * CGFloat(i)+degree2Radian(a: adjustment))
            points.append(CGPoint(x: xpo, y: ypo))
            i -= 1;
        }
        return points
    }
}

let clock = ClockView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 400))
```

Comment: Odd. I simply changed `sides` to `tickCount` and I got the output you show in the picture. I didn't have to change any code other than `sides`. Tested with Xcode 9.3.1 playground.

Comment: @rmaddy, did you test with a square view?  It looks fine if the view is square because then `midX` and `midY` are the same value.

Comment: Good catch. I did.

Comment: @rmaddy, I started with a square view as well and was just as confused.  I then just decided to try a long thin view to see what OP's code would do that I discovered the problem.  OP really needed to include a picture.